# React: close other SubMenus when another SubMenu open

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to close all other open SubMenu when the user opens a SubMenu.

Can anyone help me to find a solution?

My code:

Menu.tsx ->

```
const Menu: React.FC = ({ data }) => {
    return (
        <nav className={styles.headerMenu}>
            {
                data.map((item, index) => <MenuItem key={index} item={item} /> )
            }
        </nav>
    )
}
```

MenuItem.tsx ->

```
const MenuItem: React.FC = ({ item }) => {

   let [subMenuOpened, setSubMenuOpened] = useState<boolean>(false);

   const switchMenu = (condition) => setSubMenuOpened(condition !== null ? condition : !subMenuOpened)

   const SubMenu: React.FC = () => { /* Code to render submenu */ }

   return (
       <section  onMouseEnter={()=> item.subMenu && switchMenu(true)} onMouseLeave={() => item.subMenu && switchMenu(false)}>
           <a href={item.href}>{item.title}</a>
           //Render SubMenu if item has submenu and it is open
           { (item.subMenu && subMenuOpened) && <SubMenu  /> }
       </section>
   )
}
```

[An example of what I mean](https://streamable.com/lkhlko)

Comment: Generally, if a sibling needs to know about other sibling state, you move the state up to the parent. So, you'd keep track of which submenu was open in the Menu component, not the MenuItem, and close all but the selected one there.

Comment: How can I keep track of which submenu was open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Nikki9696](https://stackoverflow.com/users/456669/nikki9696) answered your question [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67959230/react-close-other-submenus-when-another-submenu-open/69420197#comment120117997_67959230):

> Generally, if a sibling needs to know about other sibling state, you
> move the state up to the parent. So, you'd keep track of which submenu
> was open in the Menu component, not the MenuItem, and close all but
> the selected one there.

so I will show you an example of what they meant:

```js
const Menu: React.FC = ({ data }) => {
    const keys = data.map(function(item,key) { return { key:key, close: null, item: item}});
    onOpen=(key)=>{
    // this will close all menus except the current one
    keys.forEach(x=>{
      if (x.key !== key && x.close !== null)
          x.close(); // Close should be set by child eg MenuItem.
     }) 
    }
    return (
        <nav className={styles.headerMenu}>
            {
                keys.map((item, index) => <MenuItem onOpen={onOpen} key={index} item={item} /> )
            }
        </nav>
    )
}

const MenuItem: React.FC = ({ item, onOpen }:{item: any, onOpen:Function}) => {

   let [subMenuOpened, setSubMenuOpened] = useState<boolean>(false);
    item.close = ()=> { setSubMenuOpened(false); } /// this is so the parent will trigger close
   const switchMenu = (condition) => setSubMenuOpened(condition !== null ? condition : !subMenuOpened)
   useEffect(() =>{
    if (subMenuOpened)
          onOpen(item.key); // trigger parent
   
   }, [subMenuOpened]);
   const SubMenu: React.FC = () => { /* Code to render submenu */ }

   return (
       <section  onMouseEnter={()=> item.item.subMenu && switchMenu(true)} onMouseLeave={() => item.subMenu && switchMenu(false)}>
           <a href={item.item.href}>{item.item.title}</a>
           //Render SubMenu if item has submenu and it is open
           { (item.item.subMenu && subMenuOpened) && <SubMenu  /> }
       </section>
   )
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement your code in my project and I obtained many errors with this piece of code:

      const keys = useState(data.map((item, key) => { key: key, close: null, item: item }));

Can you help me to fix this?

However the concept is very clear, thank you!

Comment: What is the errors, I can only see that it is missing (. I have fixed it. You should know what keys should containe right.

Comment: Simple old js work best. Updated my answer. Try it now

Comment: Everything works properly! Thank you for the clear explanation